# How to use View buttons to pace a foreach in Controller?

Tags: php, javascript, html

All,

I'm building a small PHP site using an MVC pattern.  Inside my Controller, I have an array of articles that I want to send to the View page.  However, I want the articles to appear one at a time in the View, and only change to the next one when the user clicks on one of several buttons.  One button just allows the user to see the next article, other buttons allow the user to "grade" or endorse the article (this info is sent back to the controller) **and** move on to the next article.

How should I do that?  The buttons are within a form, and I have Javascript functions attached to each.  A simplified version of the code would look like that:

In Controller:

```
<?php
  $array=array(10,11,12,13,14,15,16);
  $_SESSION['next']=true;
  foreach($array as $a){
    if($_SESSION['next']){
      $_SESSION['next']=false;
      $view=$a;
    }
  }
?>
```

In View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doOne(){}
  function doTwo(){}
</script>
<form class="ReviewArticles" method='POST' accept-charset="UTF-8" action='index.php?action=reviewArticles'>
<p>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="60" name='article' id='article' WRAP=SOFT>
    <?php
      echo $view;
    ?>
  </textarea>
</p>    
<p>
  <button type="button" name='showNext1' id='showNext1' onclick="doOne()" >Show next 1</button>
  <button type="button" name='showNext2' id='showNext2' onclick="doTwo()" >Show next 2</button>
</p>
</form>
```

I need to send back to the Controller some info to load the next item in the array.  I also need to send some other data related to the user "endorsing" of the article, and I want those to take place together (only one button).

Comment: MVC does not stand for "my very code". You have no model layer, "view" is just a template.

Comment: Yes, this is a simplified version because there's really no point in reproducing the whole thing, which is big.

Comment: No it is not. What you wrote is variation of http://codeangel.org/articles/simple-php-template-engine.html as done by someone who has not discovered yet procedural programming paradigm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you have on of two options:

1) Pull the article information via an AJAX request and display when the users wishes to move onto the next article. This is the best way in my opinion as it guarantees that the user has the most up to date versions of the article.

2) Store the article information in the page when it is loaded. i.e. write the data into a javascript array, hidden html elements, or whatever your preferred method. When the user hits the button, load the article using the data stored on the page.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think AJAX is the answer.  I was hopping to find some other way....  :-)

Comment: Why? AJAX is the shit! Every site uses it almost now including this one. How do you think you are able to load content without refreshing the page here?

Comment: OK  :-)  I didn't want to use AJAX because I'm not super familiar with it.  Wrong attitude I know.  Let's do it the other way 'round: "Cool, that will give me a chance to refresh my AJAX.  Yoohoo!".

Comment: I would definitely recommend doing it with the JQuery library. It seriously makes it way too easy.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you want to do on the server-side (i.e. in PHP).  Slowing down your foreach loop will just have the effect of slowing down the delivery of the entire page in the browser.  You will also have no ability to "wait" for a user action to continue your PHP execution.

You answer lies in javascript (i.e. hiding/showing content areas based on user actions), or perhaps even AJAX (load new content to the page based on user actions) if you want to get more advanced and don;t want to download all the content up front.

Comment: I'm not sure I want to load the entire content onto the browser memory - that could potentially be a lot of stuff.  Plus, I need to do something server side after each article anyway, since the users can endorse / grade an article.  I don't want to risk storing that info in the browser and risk loosing it.